# Which class to extends when overriding UrlMatcher in Symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony4

Coming from SF3, I have to resolve the router deprecated class parameters issue. I'm trying to override the URL Matcher (to handle the locale on the URL in a custom way).

Right now I see 2 classes: the `UrlMatcher` and the `CompiledUrlMatcher`.

Which class is the right one to extend if I want to override the default `UrlMatcher`?

Is the *"correct way"* for overriding the `UrlMatcher` to decorate `Symfony\Component\Routing\Matcher\UrlMatcherInterface` in Symfony 4?

-----------Edit 1

I tried to define my service like this but it does not seem to work at all:

```
<service id="myapp.localization.routing.url_matcher" class="MyApp\LocalizationBundle\Routing\UrlMatcher" decorates="Symfony\Component\Routing\Matcher\UrlMatcherInterface">
```

Is there anything that I miss here?